# Laravel send value from table row to controller

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to get values from selected row when button "edit" is clicked. I get row id in controller via button

```
value="{{ $record->id }}"
```

but I can not get name from

```
<td id="name" contenteditable="true">{{ $record->name }}</td>
```

I know that I do not have name so I writed jquery script:

```
$('#edit').on('click', function () {
    var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('#name').text();
});
```

and when I write window.alert(name); I see selected row value. So how to send it to controller. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easiest way to do it:
First you declare your route in the route file:

```
Route::get('somename/{id}/{name}','your_controller@your_method')->name('route_name');
```

Second in your view call the route in an side href per example:

```
<a href="{{route('route_name',['id'=>$record->id,'name'=>$record->name] )}}"
```

Make sure the route_name in the href matches the route_name in the route.

Third and last retrieve the id from the controller as so:

```
public function your_method($id,$name){
//you can access $id and $name now
}
```

Comment: I can get id in my controller but not name. I have button with value id. I need to get name from table row.

Comment: check answer to pass multiple values

Comment: But I dont need a link or values in it. I have table with rows and in each row i print name. Now I want to edit it and need to get name in controller when edit button is clicked. There is problem that in table I can not write name="name" only id